# R definining function to take columns as input instead of value

Tags: r, function

I have a function looking like this :

```
is_nickname = function(first_name1, first_name2, nicknames){
  first_name1_dict_vals <- nicknames[which(nicknames$name ==  first_name1), ]
  first_name2_dict_vals <- nicknames[which(nicknames$name ==  first_name2), ]

  if (rowSums(first_name2 == first_name1_dict_vals) > 0 ) {
    return(1)
  } else if (rowSums(first_name1 == first_name2_dict_vals) > 0 ){
    return (1)
  } else {
    return(0)
    }
}
```

which returns 1 if either of the names matches to a nickname of the other and 0 otherwise. This works when specifying the names as such:

```
is_nickname('will','bill',nicknames)
```

however, I would like to pass column names from a dataframe into this instead. say check$first_name1 and check$first_name2, which just contain strings for first names in my dataset.

How would you rewrite the function to output a vector corresponding to the names? I would insert this vector back into the 'check' dataframe as a new column of 1's and 0's. Thanks

edit: the nicknames dataframe has a column 'names' and columns next to it for corresponding nicknames, and is separate from the check dataframe.

```
name<-c('john','bob','sarah','joe')
mm1<-c('jon','rob',NA,'joseph')
mm2<-c('jono','robert',NA,NA)
nicknames_head<-data.frame(name,mm1,mm2)

a1<-c('data','data','data','data')
a2<-c('data','data','data','data')
first_nm1<-c('jon','harry','bob','joe')
first_nm2<-c('john','harry','robert','cain')
is_nickname_should_look_like<-c(1,1,1,0)
check_head<-data.frame(a1,a2,first_nm1, first_nm2,is_nickname_should_look_like)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change the `is_nickname` function a little to handle missing values in  `nicknames` and empty dataframes.

```
is_nickname = function(first_name1, first_name2, nicknames){

  if(is.na(first_name1) | is.na(first_name2)) return(0)
  first_name1_dict_vals <- nicknames[which(nicknames$name ==  first_name1), ]
  first_name2_dict_vals <- nicknames[which(nicknames$name ==  first_name2), ]

  if (nrow(first_name1_dict_vals) >0 && 
          rowSums(first_name2 == first_name1_dict_vals, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ) {
       return(1)
   } else if (nrow(first_name2_dict_vals) >0 && 
          rowSums(first_name1 == first_name2_dict_vals, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ){
       return (1)
   } else {
     return(0)
   }
}
```

and then call it using `mapply`

```
check_head$answer <- mapply(function(x, y) is_nickname(x, y, nicknames_head), 
                     check_head$first_nm1, check_head$first_nm2)
```

**data**

Make sure the data is read as characters and not factors.

```
nicknames_head<-data.frame(name,mm1,mm2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
check_head<-data.frame(a1,a2,first_nm1, first_nm2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: 1. 'Error in mapply(function(x, y) is_nickname(x, y, nicknames), check$first_nm1,  :  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length'.. 

 2. 'Error in nicknames$name : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors' ..

I get these two errors for your two solutions respectively. I think this might be because of the separate nicknames dataframe?

Comment: @badatr Can you provide a reproducible example? Share `dput(head(check))` and `dput(head(nicknames))` so that it is easier to help?

Comment: @badatr but your function `is_nickname` does not work with your data? `is_nickname('will','bill',nicknames_head)`

Comment: ah sorry, i didn't include will in the example data. is_nickname('bob','rob',nicknames_head) should work

Comment: @badatr I have updated the answer. Can you check now? Note that 2nd row for `"harry"` is 0 because it is not present in `nicknames_head`.

Comment: 'harry' being 0 is ok. I still get the error:  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Comment: Can you test this on the sample data that you have provided first before applying it to original data? Does it still give you an error?

Comment: It works with the sample data but not with my actual data. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Do you have `NA` values in `first_nm1` or `first_nm2`? Maybe for that case we can return 0. I have updated the answer.